# Uninstall Ruby on Rails, Ruby and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I want to remove the existing Rubies and all their gems for a clean install. I have removed Rails, Ruby  and RVM, but running

```
ruby -v
```

still shows:

```
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
```

`which ruby` shows `/usr/local/bin/ruby`, and `gem env` shows

```
RubyGems Environment:

  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 353) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - /home/akhil/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: You need to show us more information. *Where* is that installed? `which ruby` will help. Because it's an older version of Ruby I suspect it wasn't installed from source, but we won't know without more information. `gem env` might also help. Append the output of both of those to your question by editing it and pasting the text in. Indent it by four spaces so it's properly formatted.

Comment: which ruby shows /usr/local/bin/ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have the system installed Ruby. Try to remove it from the package manager.

Try to get the path of your Ruby with:

```
which ruby
```

and if you use an RPM distribution you can see the package by issuing:

```
rpm -qf /path/to/ruby
```

or

```
dpkg-query -S /path/to/ruby
```

In case of a deb packages.

Comment: which ruby shows /usr/local/bin/ruby

Answer (score 0):

For the most basic case (e.g. you want
to try clearing out a bad install), rvm
uninstall literally just removes the
folder under ~/.rvm/rubies. In most
cases, you should instead use rvm
remove. You can uninstall one or many rubies.
If you're using many, please ensure
you seperate the ruby string with a
comma, e.g.: $ r vm u n i n s t a l l r e e , 1 . 8 . 7 Removing a ruby removes both the
install and the source.

RVM DOCUMENTATION INDEX

RVM Autolibs Basics Best Practices Prerequisites Installation Configuration Upgrading CLI Info About Myths Offline Interpreters MRI/YARV (ruby) JRuby (jruby) Rubinius (rbx) MagLev (maglev) MacRuby (macruby) Rubies Installing Rubies Patching Rubies Upgrading Rubies Setting Default RubyGems Info Removing List Strings Docs Alias Named Rubies gemsets Basics Initial Creating Using Listing Deleting Emptying Exporting (dumping) Importing (loading) Copying Global Ignoring Set Actions do tests benchmark Workflow Scripting with RVM rvmrc Project Workflow Prompt IRBRC Hooks Completion Subshells Examples Proxy GNU Screen chruby

Comment: please take the time to format this so it's more readable. Help is available for the editor: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help